# Django error on running server and making migrations:

Tags: django, namespaces, admin

I get the following error on running my server, following making migrations and migrating:

**ERROR**

```
Warnings: 
?:(urls.W005) URL namespace 'admin' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace.
```

Is anyone able to explain the above error and also suggest ways of resolving it?

Answer (score 0):

Check in your url.py. You have multiple namespace name with same value.

url(r'^',include('', namespace='*Check Here*'))

Comment: Which url.py? And what do you mean by multiple namespace name? Do you mean that the same namespace value cannot be in different url.py files in different apps? Please could you clarify?

Comment: Which url.py? 
- I am talking about Django Project's url.py file not each individual app's url.py.

what do you mean by multiple namespace name?
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces
 
Do you mean that the same namespace value cannot be in different url.py files in different apps?
- app level urls should have namespaces.

Can you post your code?